# Subversion and Displaying repository like Mercurial

Tags: svn, mercurial

Is there a way to display the repository and it's changes through a html similar to how Mercurial provides a hgwebdir.cgi script that you can use.

I know it can probably be coded up, but is there something already built out there?

Any Advice Appreciated,
Thanks, 
D

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could always use [hgsubversion](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/overview) and then use Mercurial's web view. If you just want to view (not push changes back up to SVN) that would be a very simple way to do it especially if you're already using Mercurial. I have a [patch](https://bitbucket.org/magao/hgsubversion-tags) that adds the SVN revision as a transient tag to each node which would then be displayed in the web view (these tags are not displayed in `hg tags`).

BTW, I also have [some patches](https://bitbucket.org/magao/hgsubversion) to handle certain errors that occur when pulling a lot of SVN repos. They're not in a final state - I'm currently working on getting them reviewed and pulled into the main repo - but I've used them to pull >40000 revisions into a 7GB hg repository.